# Group-by and having aggregates to eliminate records

Tags: sql, mysql, relational-database

I have a temporary table like this.

```
playlist_id |   item_id  |    passed
-----------------------------------------
 123        |   111      |    true
 123        |   111      |    false
 123        |   111      |    true
 123        |   112      |    true
 456        |   212      |    false
 789        |   212      |    true
```

I need to reduce the results so that if for a `playlist_id, item_id` if and only if all of the values in `passed` are true, so in this case I'd want:

```
playlist_id |   item_id  |    passed
-----------------------------------------
 123        |   112      |    true
 789        |   212      |    true
```

Because the second record has a `false` for the `playlist_id, item_id` pair, the entire pairing group needs to be eliminated.
I've tried using `group by` and `having`, so

```
select 
  playlist, 
  item_id
from 
  temp table
group by
  playlist_id,
  item_id
having passed = true
```

But it is giving me all pairs that have at least a single `true` value.

How do I eliminate all `playlist_id, item_id` records if any one of its boolean `passed` fields is false?

Cheers!

Comment: `having passed = true` is invalid SQL. MySQL should throw an error. As it doesn't, this indicates that you are running MySQL in its notorious cheat mode. You should never do that. Always `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'` in MySQL. And as this isn't set by default this also indicates that you might be running a very old MySQL version in which case you should upgrade.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner do not *set* sql_mode to that, just include it in the list of modes

Comment: @ThorstenKettner thanks for the advice.  It works as it is currently, so I guess I'm in cheat mode.  I have inherited an ancient project running mysql 5.5 and am making moves to get the data into AWS Aurora now that should give me wire compat, but alas the client needs features now also.  I will keep this advice in mind - thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an aggregated value in `HAVING`. Otherwise, you're just testing a random row in each group.

Use `MIN(passed)` to get the minimum value of `passed` in each group. This will be `1` if all the values are `true`, `0` if there are any `false` values.

```
SELECT playlist, item_id
FROM temp_table
GROUP BY playlist, item_id
HAVING MIN(passed) = true
```